# Right way to add dependency for jstl

Tags: maven, jstl

I was following a tutorial on jsp and when the author wanted to use jstl he added the following dependencies 
in the pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
<dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My question is, will

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jstp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

not be enough to work with jstl?.

Comment: Throw away that tutorial as soon as possible. Consult Oracle's own ones or a normal book. A good starting point is our JSTL wiki page. Hover your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag which you've put on the question until a box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 0):

This dependency is enough

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2